# Check if plugin exists/active "class_exists()" does not work on plugin territory

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I have a simple if statement:

```
if (class_exists('Woocommerce')) {
    echo 'yes';
 } else {
    echo 'no';
}
```

This works fine when using it in a theme file (functions.php for example).
But when I'm using it on a plugin (plugins/myplugin/myplugin.php) it doesn't work at all.  How can I check if the plugin exists/is-active within my plugin to enable/disable some features? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Woo Commerce provides [code](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/create-a-plugin/) to check to see if WooCommerce is installed :

```
/**
 * Check if WooCommerce is active
 **/
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {
    // Put your plugin code here
}
```

If no idea where WooCommerece install then :

```
    $all_plugins = get_plugins();
    $active_plugins = get_option( "active_plugins" );

    foreach ( $all_plugins as $plugin_path => $value ) {

        if( basename( $plugin_path, ".php" ) == 'woocommerce') {
            if( in_array( $plugin_path, $active_plugins ) ) {
                return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I wish I could have a power to downvote external sites.... what this code say is that if you install WC under a different directory it is not WC anymore :(

Comment: @Mark Kaplun. I have updated the code.

Comment: +1 for the effort, but this is really something you should do only if you have no other alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to run your code at actions triggered by the other plugin. If it has some initialization action than it is a perfect solution.

Otherwise this kind of check should better be done on the core `wp_loaded` hook and for sure not before `plugins_loaded` hook. Running it directly without any dependence on hook will just never work reliably.